# How can I wait for 3 seconds and then set a bool to true, in C#?

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

My script/game/thing make a gameobject move to the right and when I click dance (a button I created) it stops. Then when the counter (I may not need a counter but I want to wait 3 seconds) reaches like 3 (once you click on dance the counter starts) my gameobject is suppose to continue on going to the right.

If you can correct the code that would be cool.
If you can correct it and explain to me what i did wrong it would be even more awesome. I just started learning C# on Unity.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HeroMouvement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool trigger = true;
    public int counter = 0;
    public bool timer = false;

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update()
    {  //timer becomes true so i can inc the counter

        if (timer == true)
        {
            counter++;
        }

        if (counter >= 3)
        {
            MoveHero();//goes to the function moveHero
        }

        if (trigger == true)
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime); //This moves the GameObject to the right
    }

    //The button you click to dance 
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), "Dance"))
        {
            trigger = false;
            timer = true;//now that the timer is set a true once you click it,The uptade should see that its true and start the counter then the counter once it reaches 3 it goes to the MoveHero function      
        }
    }

    void MoveHero()
    {  //Set the trigger at true so the gameobject can move to the right,the timer is at false and then the counter is reseted at 0.
        trigger = true;
        timer = false;
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to go easy on the whitespace...

Comment: yeah, could've had 1/5 of the lines!

Comment: Must be paid in klocs :)

Answer (score 15):

You could do it quite easily with coroutines:

```
void Update()
{
    if (trigger == true)
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime); //This moves the GameObject to the right
}

void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), "Dance"))
        {  
           StartCoroutine(DoTheDance());
        }
    }


 public IEnumerator DoTheDance() {
    trigger = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f); // waits 3 seconds
    trigger = true; // will make the update method pick up 
 }
```

See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html for more information about Coroutines and how to use them. They are pretty neat when trying to do a timed series of events.

Comment: I needed the start coroutine line to be written like this for it to work in Unity 5 : StartCoroutine(DoTheDance());

Comment: Dead link. Is this the correct one? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Answer (score 10):

I think that the easiest way is using Invoke:

[Unity3D Invoke](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)

```html
if (timer == true) Invoke("MoveHero", 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using StartCoroutine
here is the link:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

ex:

```
   void Foo () { StartCoroutine (Begin ()); }

   IEnumerator Begin ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);

         // Code here will be executed after 3 secs
        //Do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First make counter a float.
Then change `counter++;` to `counter += Time.deltaTime`.
Update() is called for every frame so counter will be 3 on the third frame. Time.deltaTime gives you the time between this frame and the previous frame. Summing it up acts like a timer.

Answer (score -3):

I would use this if multi-threading:

```
    DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime b = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);

    while (a < b)
    {
        a = DateTime.Now;
    }

    bool = x;
```

Answer (score -8):

if you need only wait, you can use sleep method of Thread

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Comment: This will freeze the update loop. You shouldn't wait in the update loop using thread sleep.

Comment: Causing the thread to sleep isn't a good solution to this problem. @JanThomä is correct.